# Like operator showing ERROR on SQL variable

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

```
declare @schoolName varchar(max) = 'children's Garden'

select * from schools where Schoolname like @schoolName+'%'
```

This is my SQL query. When I store a string with an apostrophe there is error. How can I overcome this?

The variable `@schoolName` is coming from the code.

Comment: To use a single quote within and SQL string, double it.

Answer (score 4):

Use double apostrophes to make it valid SQL String :

```
declare @schoolName varchar(max) = 'children''s Garden'

select s.* 
from schools s 
where s.Schoolname like @schoolName + '%'
```

Comment: The variable comes from the code.

Comment: split the incoming variable at the point of " ' " in the code.